# Google IAB V3 multiple devices cache

Tags: android, google-play-services, in-app-billing, google-play, android-billing

I've been implementing an inapp-purchase solution using the google iab v3 api, and it works perfectly when buying items on one device, but I have stumbled upon one problem.

If a user has several devices on which he logs on with the same account and uses my app I would expect to have the function billingService.getPurchases(...) return the same list of purchases.
This is not the case, if I make different purchases on two devices the list of purchases is (randomly) updated on each device.

My best guess is that this is related to the fact that the google play billingService does internal caching? But if I try to buy one item already bought on another device I get the error: "You already own this item", but the list/cache is still not updated.

Is there anyone with similar experiences? 
Do you know if it is possible to force the billingservice to update against the google server?
Is there any known schedule on when the billingservice updates the cache?

Thanks
Bernt-Johan

Comment: as far as I understand the case,it is matter of refreshing the cache, and it happens generally within 24hrs.

Answer (score -1):

Simple solution is to launch the Google Play Store App, the internal cache should then be updated.